# insertar texto al inicio y entrecomillando los valores de una columna en excel a otra

Tags: excel

El problema que tengo es dada una columna1 pasar los datos [dinámicos] a
la columna2 con las siguientes condiciones:

a) entrecomillar con comillas simples cada dato de la columna1 a la
columna2 y que el primer datos se le agregue al inicio el paréntesis
izquierdo y el último dato se le agregue al final de último dato el
paréntesis derecho y que los datos se copien al clipboard
ejemplo

```
columna1 resultado de la columna2 

a                       ('a'
b                        'b'
c                        'c')
```

b) El segundo caso es similar pero al incio de la columna2 se deben
agregar un texto x de acuerdo a tres criterios lo cual hace un loop
ejemplo

```
columna1 resultado de la columna2
                           text1
a                         ('a'
b                          'b'
c                           c)    

                          text2
a                         ('a'
b                          'b'
c                           c)    

                         text2
                          ('a'
                           'b'
                            c)    

                          text3
                          ('a'
                           'b'
                            c)
```

Comment: Bienvenido joed. Falta indicar que es lo que has buscado o investigado sobre "el problema". Por favor, sigue el [tour] y revisa [ask]. Cabe hacer mención que si bien es posible usar algunas etiquetas HTML para dar formato al contenido, no todas las etiquetas son válidas.

Comment: Hola joed ¿has visto las respuestas? Puedes aceptar una o agregar comentarios para solicitar clarificación o bien ,editar tu pregunta para hacerla más clara y/o específica.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba así:

```
="('"&A1&"''"&A2&"''"&A3&"')"
```

Obviamente eso depende de la posición de las celdas.

Saludos.

Comment: Esto devuelve el resultado en una sóla celda, pero aparentemente se requiere que se devuelva cada parte en filas distintas.

Answer (score 0):

Con respecto al primer caso, a mi parecer la forma correcta de manejar esto seria por medio de condicionales
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para el segundo caso puedes utilizar el mismo método, no puedo ayudarte mas sin conocer que tipos de criterios utilizarías para asignar o no el texto

añado la formula: =IF(E5="","('"&E6&"'",IF(E7="","'"&E6&"')","'"&E6&"'"))